# How to have dynamically added fields to specific model fields and not all

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i am building an application that has a model with three fields Company,Name, position. in the same model i want to have company name as one field while the user can add name and positions for multiple candidates. the reason am trying to do that is because i didnt find any proper way to set automatically select the foreign key based on the company name entered since foreign key is a drop down list and couldnt figure out the way to make foreign key field equal to company name entered.

appreciate help and suggestions if any for the approach i have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two forms (or more usefully one form and one formset). Use form prefixes to make them distinguishable. Pass both to the template, say as `selectform` and `candidate_formset` and in the template, use

```
{{selectform}}
{{candidate_formset}}
```

The first is a company-select form. It might, for example, be

```
class CompanySelectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Candidate
        fields = ['company']
```

The second is a form, or probably a formset, for entering one, or (via a formset) as many candidates as there are to be entered. It will look like

```
class CandidateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Candidate
        fields = ['name','position']
```

Now, you use `commit=False` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)) to create objects but not save them. First, process `CandidateSelectForm`, which will give you a `Candidate` object with a valid `company` instance, but not save it. Then process the formset of `CandidateForm`, again with `commit=False`, which will give you a list of `candidate` instances with no company, again unsaved. Finally for each `candidate` in this list, set  the company field of every `candidate` to the one on the object retrieved by `CandidateSelectForm` and save it.

It will probably be easier to write a plain view function, than messing around with method overrides trying to get the class-based views to process two forms this way.

Edit - added on request.

The view could be modelled on [this one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#the-view) in the Django doc. I've made the obvious changes in line with the earlier part of the answer, but it's probably full of errors and I'm not going to debug it further here

```
def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create form instances and populate with data from the request:
        cs_form = CompanySelectForm(request.POST, prefix="cs")
        cand_form = CandidateSelectForm( request.POST, prefix="cand")
        # check whether it's valid:
        if cs_form.is_valid() and cand_form.is_valid():
            selector = cs_form.save(commit=False)
            candidate = cand_form(commit=False)
            candidate.company = selector.company
            candidate.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        cs_form = CompanySelectForm( prefix='cs')
        cand_form = CandidateSelectForm( prefix='cand')

    return render(request, 'name.html', {
        "select_form": cs_form,
        "candidate_form": cand_form,
    })
```

Once you have got this working for a single candidate, you can progress to turning `candidate_form` into a formset, documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/) which will let you enter any number of candidates to be attached to the one  selected company.

Comment: appreciate if you can write the view for the candidate form so i will replacate it to my need as am still new to django

Comment: @Mohammad_Al_Blooshi Have sketched it out. You'll have to take it from here yourself. The only way to learn is by trying over and over again until it works.